# Spark explode nested JSON with Array in Scala

Tags: arrays, json, scala, apache-spark, explode

Lets say i loaded a json file into Spark 1.6 via

```
sqlContext.read.json("/hdfs/")
```

it gives me a Dataframe with following schema:

```
root
 |-- id: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- checked: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- color: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- type: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

The DF has only one row with an Array of all my Items inside.

```
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|                id_e|           checked_e|             color_e|
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|[0218797c-77a6-45...|[false, true, tru...|[null, null, null...|
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

I want to have a DF with the arrays exploded into one item per line.

```
+--------------------+-----+-------+
|                  id|color|checked|
+--------------------+-----+-------+
|0218797c-77a6-45f...| null|  false|
|0218797c-77a6-45f...| null|  false|
|0218797c-77a6-45f...| null|  false|
|0218797c-77a6-45f...| null|  false|
|0218797c-77a6-45f...| null|  false|
|0218797c-77a6-45f...| null|  false|
|0218797c-77a6-45f...| null|  false|
|0218797c-77a6-45f...| null|  false|
...
```

So far i achieved this by creating a temporary table from the array DF and used sql with lateral view explode on these lines.

```
val results = sqlContext.sql("
SELECT id, color, checked from temptable 
lateral view explode(checked_e) temptable as checked 
lateral view explode(id_e) temptable as id 
lateral view explode(color_e) temptable as color
")
```

Is there any way to achieve this directly with Dataframe functions without using SQL? I know there is something like df.explode(...) but i could not get it to work with my Data

EDIT: It seems the explode isnt what i really wanted in the first place. 
I want a new dataframe that has each item of the arrays line by line. The explode function actually gives back way more lines than my initial dataset has.

Answer (score 5):

The following solution should work.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val data = Seq((Seq(1,2,3),Seq(4,5,6),Seq(7,8,9)))
val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data)

val udf3 = udf[Seq[(Int, Int, Int)], Seq[Int], Seq[Int], Seq[Int]]{
    case (a, b, c) => (a,b, c).zipped.toSeq
}

val df3 = df.select(udf3($"_1", $"_2", $"_3").alias("udf3"))
val exploded = df3.select(explode($"udf3").alias("col3"))

exploded.withColumn("first", $"col3".getItem("_1"))
    .withColumn("second", $"col3".getItem("_2"))
    .withColumn("third", $"col3".getItem("_3")).show
```

While it is more straightforward if using normal Scala code directly. It might be more efficient too. Spark could not help anyway if there is only one row.

```
val data = Seq((Seq(1,2,3),Seq(4,5,6),Seq(7,8,9)))
val seqExploded = data.flatMap{
    case (a: Seq[Int], b: Seq[Int], c: Seq[Int]) => (a, b, c).zipped.toSeq
}
val dfTheSame=sqlContext.createDataFrame(seqExploded)
dfTheSame.show
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be simple like this:

```
df.withColumn("id", explode(col("id_e")))
  .withColumn("checked", explode(col("checked_e")))
  .withColumn("color", explode(col("color_e")))
```

Comment: well your code seems to do what i did with the sql statement, but when i checked it, i figured out that this explode isn't really what i need. My initial dataset is ~600 lines each. After the explode i have ~ 180 mil lines. what i actually want is just taking out the elements of the arrays line by line to create a new dataframe

Comment: you're right, my answer produces cartesian product, looks like @Rockie Yang solution should do it in the right way